# Haskell multiple action types inside do block gives error "Couldn't match expected type `ZMQ z a0'"

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a simple program in Haskell which listens over Zero MQ socket and publishes it to websocket connection, below is my code

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Char (isPunctuation, isSpace)
import Data.Monoid (mappend)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Exception (fromException)
import Control.Monad (forM_, forever)
import Control.Concurrent (MVar, newMVar, modifyMVar_, readMVar)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Network.WebSockets as WS
import System.ZMQ3.Monadic
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack, unpack)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Data.Text.Encoding
import Data.ByteString.Internal

main :: IO ()
main = do
        liftIO $ putStrLn "starting main..."
        WS.runServer "0.0.0.0" 9160 $ application

application :: WS.Request -> WS.WebSockets WS.Hybi00 ()
application rq = do
        liftIO $ putStrLn "starting..."
        WS.acceptRequest rq
        sink <- WS.getSink
        WS.getVersion >>= liftIO . putStrLn . ("Client version: " ++)
        msg <- WS.receiveData
        liftIO $ putStrLn $ show $ (msg:: Text)

        WS.sendTextData (msg :: Text)
        runZMQ $ do
                repSocket<- socket Rep
                s<-return $bind repSocket "tcp://*:6555"

                msg2 <- receive repSocket
                let quote = msg2
                --msg2 <- WS.receiveData
                --liftIO $ putStrLn $ quote
                WS.sendTextData $ ("test"::Text)
```

But compiler fails at statement `WS.sendTextData $ ("test"::Text)` saying below error

```
websocket_server.hs:42:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `ZMQ z a0'
                with actual type `WS.WebSockets p0 ()'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: WS.sendTextData $ ("test" :: Text)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { repSocket <- socket Rep;
            s <- return $ bind repSocket "tcp://*:6555";
            msg2 <- receive repSocket;
            let quote = msg2;
            .... }'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      runZMQ
      $ do { repSocket <- socket Rep;
             s <- return $ bind repSocket "tcp://*:6555";
             msg2 <- receive repSocket;
             let quote = msg2;
             .... }
```

I am not sure how to deal with this issue how can I make do block statements return same value when the values cannot be converted into each other?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `liftIO` should be enough for that call, but I haven't tried.

Comment: liftIO does not help as it throws similar error - Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `WS.WebSockets p0 ()'

Comment: Oh, I was looking at websockets 0.8, where all the functions are just in the `IO` monad instead of some custom monad. Which does make me wonder how the `runZMQ` call itself typechecks. Anyway, trying to run two libraries which both want to control the monad type and interspersing their calls looks like trouble.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The call to `rubZMQ` typechecks because it has type `runZMQ :: MonadIO m => (forall z. ZMQ z a) -> m a` and `WebSockets` monad is an instance of `MonadIO`.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that both the ZMQ and Websockets libraries define a "top level monad" that is *not* a monad transformer. So there is no provided way to layer the monads. This is poor design on their parts.

My suggestion would be to A) write your own ZMQ transformer or B) use the nonmonadic interface provided by ZMQ at the top level.